# Angular 12 global exception handling

Tags: angular, error-handling, interceptor

I would like to implement global exception handler in my Angular app, which will **handle only exceptions unhandled on service level**. I think this is quite common scenario, because good UX/UI should display specific error description as first. Otherwise (if not handled on service level) it should fall back to some generic error description.

Currently I couldn't find a way how to achieve desired behavior with angular interceptors, because interceptor is always called **before** the service call:

Service class:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GeneratorService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  public thisShouldBeHandledLocally(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>>(`/service1`)
    .pipe(catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      alert('I am handled by service');
      return throwError(error);
    }));
  }

  public thisShouldBeHandleByInterceptor(workspace: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>>(`/service2`);
  }
}
```

Interceptor class:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert('I am handled by interceptor');
        // handle error only if not handled by service
      })
      )
  }
}
```

`thisShouldBeHandledLocally()` will display both alerts:

1. I am handled by interceptor
2. I am handled by service

Is there any way how to achieve desired error handling?

Comment: You could use an error handler
https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

Comment: Thanks a lot, ErrorHandler is exactly I was looking for, all articles I've googled before described only interceptor approach.